# Is there any way to "cancel" the promise.done() from being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The idea is, whenever a certain scenario happens in server, I want the HTTP call to be recognised as success by the browser, but still not call the done() function of the deferred object returned by $.ajax call.

To handle this I was thinking of returning a custom HTTP code (2XX, ensuring not any of the standard HTTP success codes) from my server.
This code will be generic, and will be returned by all the server side calls that encounters this scenario

Now, in my javascript code, I want to make sure that if the return code is my custom 2XX, the promise.done method should not be called.

I was guessing something like this should work.

```
$.ajax({
    /* url parameters here */
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

      /*This code is to handle custom  return code 289
      * This code ensures that if there is an issue in getting data from api side
      * the actual promise.done() method is not called. because that would cause Javascript error*/
      if(jqXHR.status === 289){        
            // Stop promise.done from being executed
            // or override the promise.done function to something harmless  

        };
      }
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

     },
     complete: function (options, status) {

     },
     timeout: 60000
});
```

Is there any way to "cancel" the promise.done method being called, in a standard way?

Comment: `[...]2XX, ensuring not any of the standard HTTP success codes[...]` that is a bad idea, because what will you do if that code is used in future.

Comment: Considering the fact that only 10 of the 2XX codes are being used (standardised) so far, and that these codes have been in existence since past 2 decades, I am guessing its a pretty safe bet for any foreseeable future. Even if that happens, it's a 2 word code change at 2 places anyway.

Comment: So you don't want to handle that failure case in your code at all, but silently ignore that something happened? This is a really uncommon way to deal with error cases and makes the code hard to maintain, especially because it breaks default behaviour. For a `if there is an issue in getting data from api side` the most common status code would be a `503` or `504` with a  `Retry-After`  header. And then in you `catch` callback you can decide what want to handle that case.

Comment: I agree its a rather uncommon way. But the thing is, the scenario we are handling is not really a failure at all (at least its not _our_ servers failure).Hence, the powers that be doesn't want the rest call to come up as a failure in browser console.I understand that it should ideally be handled in the success callback code and the return status should be 200 as appropriate, but that would mean a lot of code changes in lot many rest calls.

Comment: I understand your concerns, as I myself also have had this case before. But you still should handle the error case in a correct way, instead of trying to hide it. Hiding really just postpones the problem until later. And even if it is not your failure, it is still one as you can't handle the request, the `503` or `504` does not say that the error is on your side, it just says that your server was not able to handle the request due to a problem (e.g. because an API server was not avalible, or returned a wrong response). So it shouldn't handled in the `done`, but in the `fail`